# Using echo in php

Tags: php, html

When you create any website you are sure to use the HTML code for building blocks and general construction site.

And often this code be in php file as it makes no sense to make a separate file, and then another inkluda ..

Pripustit have a PHP file and it contains the following code:

```
<?php
$title='Title';
$content='Content//';

echo <<<HTML
<div class='title'>$title</div>
<div class='content'>$content</div>
HTML;

?>
```

But it can still bring so

```
    <?php
$title='Title';
$content='Content//';
?>

<div class='title'><?echo$title;?></div>
<div class='content'><?echo$content;?></div>
```

In general, the question is what method should I use? According to the idea of a second method should be faster, but at a very much? Or is it possible not to think about it and write a more convenient?

And that, for example if in echo to output a lot of HTML code?

Comment: Use what makes sense. If you want to know what most people do then go to GitHub and look at the [Trending page for PHP](https://github.com/trending/php).

Comment: Smarty or other template engine

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Definitely, if you use a smaller set of commands, the speed will be faster. In this case, most likely, it is better to give up the echo, as it is to anything.

If we use the **[example](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.microtime.php)** functions and measure the output with and without echo, the difference will be about half a second is not in favor of the echo.

Comment: Outputting stuff in PHP is very fast. It is the least important thing to worry about.